# Error sending temperature data from Arduino to Matlab

Tags: matlab, arduino, serial-port

I am trying to send temperature sensor data from arduino to matlab using serial communication. The temperature data are displayed on the Arduino serial monitor but I couldn't get the data in Matlab. The following error occurs. I've tried every possible ways to get the data by putting a pause(3) before fscanf but it still doesn't work.

> Warning: Unsuccessful read: A timeout occurred before the Terminator was reached.
>   'serial' unable to read any data. For more information on possible reasons, see Serial Read Warnings. 
>      NaN

My matlab code as follows

```
if ~isempty(instrfind)
    fclose(instrfind);
    delete (instrfind);
end

waitTime = 10;

s = serial('COM4','BAUD',9600);

waitTime = duration(0,waitTime,0);
t = datetime('now') - startTime;

while t < waitTime
    fopen(s);
    pause(3);
    idn = fscanf(s);
    fclose(s);

    serialData = str2double(idn);
    corrData = serialData;
    disp(corrData);
end


clear a;
clear s;
```

Comment: The fopen and close within the loop is probably wrong. Usually you open the connection and leave it open, until everything is read. What kind of data is the arduino sending? Text data?

Comment: I'm not sure what kind of data is arduino sending as I'm absolute beginner in arduino but I'm sending temperature sensor data to matlab. The data is showing in arduino using Serial.print(bme.readTemperature());.

Answer (score 0):

`fscanf` will return when the first terminator is found. This is usually carriage return (CR). Since you are using `Serial.print(bme.readTemperature());` there is never a CR sent by the Arduino. Try `Serial.println(bme.readTemperature());`

Comment: Hello. Thank you for your reply. It is showing the error message but the data from the temperature ie 26.32 degree is never sent to the Matlab. Instead, it is showing NaN. What could possibly be the reason why the value is not sent?

Comment: I've managed to solve the problem by putting the fopen(s) and fclose(s) outside of the while loop. It is showing the values but for the first few values it is showing NaN.